# Check if AWS profile is logged is using powershell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I have a powershell script, and at the beginning it sets AWSCredential, like below:

`Set -AWSCredentials -profileName myProfileName`

In the same script, I have a line that should only execute if the profile above is logged in successfully, otherwise don't execute that line.

How do I check that, that it logged in ok

(If logged in ok)
{
Execute my line here
}

Comment: You could use the output of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-STSCallerIdentity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get sts details of the account,

`if (aws sts get-caller-identity) { do the stuff }`